# dates semantics in RSS

Tags: rss, feedparser

I'm reading the documentation of [feedparser](http://www.feedparser.org/docs/date-parsing.html).

It describes 4 attributes related to date

1. published
2. updated
3. created
4. expired

What do these attributes mean in relation to [RSS specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)? It describes only `pubDate`

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Feedparser](http://www.feedparser.org/) covers several syndication formats, for example [Atom syndication format (RFC 4287)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287). That is why you see a mis-match with the (relatively old) RSS standard.

The documentation for feedparser has details about the semantics and where in the feed it picks up the values:

[Published:](http://www.feedparser.org/docs/reference-entry-published.html)

> The date this entry was first published

[Updated:](http://www.feedparser.org/docs/reference-entry-updated.html)

> The date this entry was last updated

[Created:](http://www.feedparser.org/docs/reference-entry-created.html)

> The date this entry was first created (drafted)

[Expired:](http://www.feedparser.org/docs/reference-entry-expired.html)

> The date this entry is set to expire [...] This element is rare.

Comment: So, feed parser solved this for me? It extracts data from various feed types and I have to test if the value exists? Atom is newer?

Comment: If my feeds are only RSS I should probably use `updated` value?